# Maven : How to filter one file with own plugin

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

I'm modifying some maven3 plugin and I just need to filter with file using some properties already defined in the pom starting the whole process.

I haven't found much doc/examples on the topic and all my attempts failed.

First one :

```
 /**
 * @component
 * @required
 * @readonly
 */
private MavenFileFilter mavenFileFilter;
```

and then in my code :

```
mavenFileFilter.copyFile(tempFile, resultingFile, true, getProject(), Collections.<String> emptyList(), true, "utf-8", session);
```

However nothing happens : the replacement isn't done.

Then I saw various examples evolving around

```
MavenResourcesExecution mavenResourcesExecution = new MavenResourcesExecution(resources, outputDirectory, getProject(), "utf-8", null, nonFilteredFileExtensions, session);
```

However I don't get how to put in there the file I want... Resource has no constructor with actual content...

Any help welcome!

Best

EDIT (more context) :
The context is the following : we built a web app deployed at many customers' servers.

On one hand, the folder hierarchy depends from customer to customer.

On the other hand, we have some default logback.xml config file, which needs to be filtered (to use the correct folder hierarchy of the given customer server). This file sits in some common project. We would also like to be able to specialize this logback.xml, when we wish so, on a per customer basis. We've put these files in the source folders of the respective common project/customer project.

As such, the plugin doing the packaging now looks into each artifact, by order of dependencies, and pick up the first logback.xml and put it where needed. It also needs to do the filtering to put the right folders.

It all works apart the last bit...

Does it make sense ? Any better way ?

Thanks again

Comment: The issue is that I need to do that later in the lifecycle : it's some config file which I need to customize for the given context...

Comment: Ain't the existing filtering capabilities not enough?

Comment: @khmarbaise I'm sure he'd like to use existing filtering capabilities but what are the APIs and how do you use them? That is the essence of this question. the Maven APIs are poorly documented. It makes writing a plugin require a huge amount of trial and error. I'm actually struggling with this exact issue (which is how I landed here).

Comment: I would suggest to take a look [here](http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-filtering/usage.html)

Comment: @khmarbaise: That link is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!!

Comment: @spaceborg: I've implemented a plugin of my own that does copying and filtering of resources, based on khmarbaise's link. You can see it here, maybe it will help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22362162/192801

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to take a look at this:

```xml
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>copy-resources</id>
            <!-- here the phase you need -->
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/extra-resources</outputDirectory>
              <resources>          
                <resource>
                  <directory>src/non-packaged-resources</directory>
                  <filtering>true</filtering>
                </resource>
              </resources>              
            </configuration>            
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    ...
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

Why do you need to implement a plugin which only copies resources within an other life cyclce phase.

Comment: I put more context in the question, I hope it helps... However, after editing it and thanks to you, I thought of a new way : a phase after my plugin action and before the packing of all the stuff, is possible. Let's see :) And thanks again !