# How to call maven-resources-plugin programmatically

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I am writing a custom Maven plugin and part of the plugin's job is to filter-copy some resources.

The code I've written looks like this:

```
CopyResourcesMojo rm = new CopyResourcesMojo();             
rm.setOutputDirectory(outputDir); //determined dynamically in a loop
rm.setOverwrite(true);
rm.setFilters(filters);  //determined dynamically in a loop
rm.setResources(this.resources);  //Actually is of type List<Resource>
rm.execute(); //NulPointerException because rm's project member is null.
```

This throws a `NullPointerException` because the `CopyResourceMojo` doesn't have access to my mojo's `project`, and the `CopyResourceMojo` doesn't have a `setProject()` method I could use.

I *have* looked into using `mojo-executor-maven-plugin`. The problem I have with it is that using this library to call a plugin involves writing code that mirrors what the XML config would be for that plugin. My plugin will receive a list of resources (just like the `maven-resources-plugin` could) so if I am going to use `mojo-executor-maven-plugin`, I think I would have to write code to evaluate the inclusions and exclusions. I was hoping to make use of the `maven-resources-plugin` for this, so that behaviour is 100% consistent with other plugins that take resource lists as parameters.

Is there any other way to call a plugin from code, or to inject a project into another mojo?  Or some other way to accomplish this?

Comment: The question is what you exactly like to achieve with your plugin? Are you really sure that you need to write an special plugin to fit your needs? Can you explain them may be other plugin fulfill already all things you need?

Comment: @khmarbaise: Based on a list of values in the plugin's configuration, the plugin creates a series of custom filter files and selectively filters certain resources with specific files. It actually *can* be done without any special plugins, but the configuration to do that is kinda scary, and I fear it will become a maintenance nightmare. Achieving the same thing (creating the filters) is much easier in Java than in a pom file. Now I want to be able run the copy/filter process from within the plugin, with specific filters on specific resources.

Comment: @khmarbaise: It's very specific to part of our build process, I haven't seen any plugins that do anything similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did eventually find a way to do this using MavenResourcesFiltering and MavenResourcesExecution. Document is here: http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-filtering/usage.html

I was able to get this code to do what I wanted:

```
/* Class members */
@Parameter(defaultValue="${project}",required=true, readonly=true)
protected MavenProject project;

@Parameter( defaultValue = "${session}", required = true, readonly = true )
protected MavenSession session;

@Component( role=org.apache.maven.shared.filtering.MavenResourcesFiltering.class, hint="default")
protected MavenResourcesFiltering mavenResourcesFiltering;

@Parameter( property = "encoding", defaultValue = "${project.build.sourceEncoding}" )
protected String encoding;

@Parameter
protected List<Resource> resources;


...

//Inside my plugin's execute() method: 
List<String> nonFilteredFileExtensions = new ArrayList<String>();
//resources is a parameter to my plugin, dir and filters are calculated within the plugin
MavenResourcesExecution mre = new MavenResourcesExecution(resources, dir, this.project, this.encoding, filters, nonFilteredFileExtensions, session);
mavenResourcesFiltering.filterResources(mre);
```

And I define resources in my plugin's configuration the usual way:

```
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>G:/MyPluginProject/src/test/resources/project-to-test/resources</directory>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>*.DAT</exclude>
        </excludes>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

What's odd is that for `<directory>`, absolute paths work fine but I can't seem to get it to work with an expression such as `${basedir}`. I'm probably overlooking something obvious here...

Answer (score 1):

Besides the mojo-executor there is no direct way to call another plugin from plugin code.

However plugins can execute a parallel lifecycle which can call other plugins via its own XML configuration.

http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/writing-plugins-sect-plugins-lifecycle.html

Comment: Interesting. I guess I could have my main plugin create/modify the configuration for the plugin it's about to call?